# Best way of passing values from a button with as3 event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, mouseevent

I develop my own way of doing this simple task. However, I'm now wondering if there is a better way to do it.

The buttons:

```
var menuBtnEscrit:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var mbe:btnEscritorio = new btnEscritorio();
menuBtnEscrit.addChild(mbe);
menuBtnEscrit.val = "escrit";
menuBtnEscrit.x = 80;
menuBtnEscrit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, novoCont);
dMenu.addChild(menuBtnEscrit);
var menuBtnPublic:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var mbp:btnPublic = new btnPublic();
menuBtnPublic.addChild(mbp);
menuBtnPublic.val = "public";
menuBtnPublic.x = 244;
menuBtnPublic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, novoCont);
dMenu.addChild(menuBtnPublic);
```

And I can keep going, or create buttons trough some algorithm, and put more properties and take advantage of a MovieClip.

The handler:

```
private function novoCont(e=null){
  if(e!=null) selecCont = new String(e.target.parent.val);
  clearDisplay(dSubMenu);
  clearDisplay(dConteudo);
  var func:String = "cont_"+selecCont;
  this[func]();
}
```

As you can see, there is some common task for all buttons.

If I click the first button, it will call cont_escrit() function. This mechanics works, but it is the best practice? Is there a way of optimize it?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class BaseButton extends Button {

   private var _func:Function;

   public function get handler():Function {
        return _func;
   }

   public function set handler(value:Function):void {
       _func = value;
   }

}
```

So hero you can create mbe like this

```
 mbe  = new BaseButton ();
 mbe.hanler = cont_escrit;
```

The event hanler would be

```
private function novoCont(e=null){
    if(e!=null) {

        var  selecContent:BaseButton  = e.targe as BaseButton ;

       var handler:Function = selecContent.handler;
       handler();
     }
}
```

Here is an example.

```
var menuBtnEscrit:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var mbe:btnEscritorio = new btnEscritorio();
menuBtnEscrit.addChild(mbe);
//menuBtnEscrit.val = "escrit";
menuBtnEscrit.func = this.cont_escrit;
menuBtnEscrit.x = 80;
menuBtnEscrit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, novoCont);


private function novoCont(e=null){

   if(e!=null) {
       var mc:MovieClip = e.target  as MovieClip;
       var func:Function = mc.func;
       func();
   }
  clearDisplay(dSubMenu);
  clearDisplay(dConteudo);

}
```

Comment: Did you mean [`extends SimpleButton`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/SimpleButton.html)?

Comment: btnEscritorio is a movieClip, right? So you could just set btnEscritorio.func like btnEscritorio.val without extends any class.

Comment: Is a MovieClip, however, when you generate swf it is exported as a class definition and doesn't accept further set functions and properties like this. Maybe there is a way but I don't know, Pan method seams ok, I'll try it.

Comment: But where is my button? Where is btnEscritorio?

Comment: I don't understand your last question. btnEscritorio.func is just a variable of btnEscritorio, just like your btnEscritorio.val.